# Is it usual to have many expired auth tokens in database? Shouldn't system delete them automatically?

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have developed a web application which uses a library for authentication and authorization matters, and the using protocol is `OAuth 2.0`. After a while I found out that all of the access tokens which have been expired and they're not being used anymore, are still stored in database and the user should revoke them to be removed. Now I'm wondering is it alright? Cause many tokens are too old, shouldn't I remove them after a while? For example removing all the tokens which have been expired 30 days ago! by using a scheduled task.

P.S: In my case I'm using Django + DRF + oauth2 provider for auth management.

Answer (score 0):

I used knox auth library and didn't face your problem, in my case it's automatically deleted after expired date.

But if your question is about scheduling in Django You can use one of libraries that can help you, like [celery](https://celeryproject.org)

but, there is another easy method to add scheduled task in Django.
I use threads to do the job.
by creating a thread in main function to do your task like bellow code in manage.py in Django.

```
def periodic_check():
    while True:
        # some code ...
        time.sleep(500)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=periodic_check, daemon=True)
    x.start()
    main()
```